# multiple divs with different css

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I'm working with MapQuest and Leaflet. I can have multiple maps on the screen at the same time. I have edited the `leaflet.css` file, and to change the size of certain icons within the map, I get the zoom that the map is currently at and change the icon sizes in the `leaflet.css` file like such:

```
if (Map.getZoom()=== 13)
{
    $('.leaflet-label').css('font-size', '24px');
}
```

The above is for a label, but it is pretty much the same for icon/markers. Now because I have 4 maps, they all use the same `leaflet.css` file. So when I zoom in on one particular map, the labels/markers/icons for all the other maps change too, even though the zoom is being utilized only on one map.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.label.css" />

<div class="maps" style="width:400px; height:400px; left:1400px;" id="map"></div>
<div class="maps" style="width:400px; height:400px; top:-400px;" id="MAP2"></div>
<div class="maps" style="width:400px; height:400px; top:-800px; left:960px;" id="MAP3"></div>
<div class="maps" style="width:400px; height:400px; top:-1200px; left:550px;" id="MAP4"></div>
```

Is there a way to set it up so that each div acts independently of the others?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you to have multiple classes set to a single element. And please, move all these inline styles to a proper stylesheet. Ah, and remove all these useless blank spaces between the attributes.

Comment: People are downrating this because your text is making little sense. you talking about '4 maps', 'icons' and 'zoom' without further explanation. 

Rephrase you question with more deepth and explanations.

Comment: as MelanciaUK said, you can have multiple classes on a single element. So you could use one base class to style what the divs should hace in common, and then add another unique class (or ID) to every `div` that styles it's own properties. Like: `<div class="maps-base maps-first"`

Comment: @AndersÖstman no need to add anything, the divs already have ids.

Comment: @Christophe Aah... I didn't see them, they where so far away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css, you have the `.maps{}` class already (I'm assuming) which holds all of the default shared style setting for all maps.

You can then specify settings for each of the different IDs if you like i.e.,

```
#MAP2{
    width:400px; 
    height:400px; 
    top:-400px;
}
#MAP3{
    width:400px; 
    height:400px; 
    top:-800px;    
    left:960px;
}
#MAP4{
    width:400px; 
    height:400px; 
    top:-1200px;   
    left:550px;
}
```

Then, you can choose which map to zoom by using the id selector instead of the class selector.